# Angular 2 external style doesn't get inlined to header

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template

I have this component definition in typescript:

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '/views/sandbox.html',
    styleUrls: ['/styles/sandbox.css'],
    styles: [`.wow { background-color: red; }`],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class SandBox { }
```

According to this article: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/25/styling-angular-2-components.html
both the style in the styles section and in the external stylesheet should be inlined into the header by angular.

Unfortunately, the second does not get injected, angular injects only the one in the styles section.

I have tried accessing /styles/sandbox.css from browser, it is fine. Angular is also able to access /views/sandbox.html so i have no idea why it is not happening.

I am using: "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.2" (latest beta AFAIK)

Comment: Does it inject when you remove the styleUrls property?

Comment: The 'styles' is always injected. It is the other which is not.

Comment: Can't you just drop the first slash in your absolute URL so it looks like this `styles/sandbox.css`? That worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made some tests and strangely styles from the `sandbox.css` only applies if you use a relative paths within the `styleUrls` attribute:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: '/views/sandbox.html',
  styleUrls: ['../styles/sandbox.css'],
  styles: [`.wow { background-color: red; }`],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**Edit**

After having a look at the source code, Angular2 prevents from using absolute path for the `styleUrls`. See this line:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/compiler/style_url_resolver.ts#L12

  ```
  export function isStyleUrlResolvable(url: string): boolean {
    if (isBlank(url) || url.length === 0 || url[0] == '/') return false; // <-----
    var schemeMatch = RegExpWrapper.firstMatch(_urlWithSchemaRe, url);
    return isBlank(schemeMatch) || schemeMatch[1] == 'package' || schemeMatch[1] == 'asset';
  }
  ```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: It works, thanks! However, i wonder whether it is a bug... as absolute url works with 'templateUrl' but not with 'styleUrls'

Comment: After having a look at the source code, there is a test that prevents from using this... I updated my answer.

Comment: I added an issue in the angular repo regarding this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6905. I'm looking forward to having an answer from them ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The Best way to fix this is use another css file for your component and add it to your StyleUrls list. Cleaner and will scale as you components grow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use systemjs and commonjs module dependencies loader, to load templates, styles and other files.

in commonjs  moduleId : module.id
in systemJs  __moduleName

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({

moduleId:module.id,
selector: "exf-header",
templateUrl: "header.html",
styleUrls:['header.css']

})

export class HeaderComponent {

}
```