# Angular2, Component not loading external css

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to load external css files into my app. For some reason the html specified is loading, but the css is not and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I also can't see a GET request for the css files in the server logs, only for the html.

Here's my component:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'portfolio',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/landing.html',
    styleUrls : ['/app/styles/landingMobile.css', '/app/styles/landingOther.css']
})

export class LandingComponent { }
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
app
--styles
----landingMobile.css
----landingOther.css
----template.css
--views
----landing.html
----template.html
--app.component.ts
--landing.component.ts
--main.ts
--portfolio.component.ts
node_modules
typings
index.html
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is a problem with absolute paths within the `styleUrls` attribute. See these links for mroe details: * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188803/angular-2-external-style-doesnt-get-inlined-to-header/35197976#35197976
* https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6905

Comment: U done with this question?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, got it to work